# Lyft API giving 504 gateway timeout for few users

Tags: oauth-2.0, lyft-api

I am calling this API
"URL: https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides?start_time=2016-01-01T00:00:01%2B00%3A00&limit=50, Header: {"Authorization"=>"Bearer tJVICf23213p1k2ksdjskadsd0KMuOVgWsdkc7rGs4g/WNKreAFqK4EroFDwj/sdjljas_dlkjasdksdfdf="}"

I get correct responses for all the users except 2.

In ruby, this is my code to call the lyft dev api

response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: url, headers: header)

It just goes inside the rescue and gives either 504 gateway timeout. Earlier, it used to give 500 internal server error.

Also, the access tokens get renewed successfully. No issue with that.

Any kind of help will be appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the issue.

We were using max limit of getting 50 rides of the user. Lyft server was giving 504 gateway timeout because it was not able to process the number of trips. We changed the max limit to 20 and it worked without any issues.